# How to make an underlined border for TextButton only in hovered or focussed state?

Tags: flutter, dart, material3

Because this button will be used a lot in the app, then it doesn't make sense to create a custom component for that. I believe it can be done easily. However, I prefer to use the theme instead. I have no problem with the changing colors in different states. My only issue is that I cannot figure out how to apply the bottom border to the text button. The following image is the design I need to follow.

[image]

This is the minimal code I have written. `_getShape()` is responsible to provide the right border when the button is in hovered/focussed state.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Theme Configuration for light and Dark themes.
class AppTextButtonTheme {
  static final TextButtonThemeData lightTheme = TextButtonThemeData(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<TextStyle?>((Set<MaterialState> states) {
        return AppThemeText.lightTheme.labelLarge;
      }),
      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((state) => _getForegroundColor(state, true)),
      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((state) => _getOverlayColor(state, true)),
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<OutlinedBorder?>((state) => _getShape(state, true)),
    ),
  );

  ...

  static OutlinedBorder? _getShape(Set<MaterialState> states, bool isLightMode) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered) || states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
      return RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        side: const BorderSide(width: 3, color: isLightMode ? Colors.blue : Colors.red),
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is the final result. This is close to what I want, but I need the bottom border only.
[image]